# jQuery - access variable out of a jQuery function

Tags: jquery

guys. I have something like this:

```
myThing = {
    str:"my string",
    setClick: function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            alert(this.str);
        });
    }
}

myThing.setClick();
```

The problem is when I click the button the function doesn't know what str is. `alert(str)` gives me an error (`str is not defined`) and no alerts. `alert(this.str)` gives me the alert but containing `undefined`.

I can see that `this` reffers to the button and the button doesn't have any attribute called `str`. So how can I access the str that is out of jQuery's function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save a reference to `this` in `setClick`, outside the `click` event handler:

```
myThing = {
    str:"my string",
    setClick: function() {
        var self = this;
        $("button").click(function() {
            alert(self.str);
        });
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PBPB4/)**.

Answer (score 3):

You can always reference the object by name

```
myThing = {
    str:"my string",
    setClick: function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            alert(myThing.str);
        });
    }
}

myThing.setClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the context of a function using the javascript function `bind`. I find it can be useful in situations such as this. It lets you define the value of `this` within the function being bound.

```
myThing = {
    str:"my string",
    setClick: function(){
        $("button").click(function(e){
            // 'this' is myThing
            // $(e.currentTarget) is the button on which the event handler was attached
        }.bind(this));
    }
}

myThing.setClick();
```